# infloor heating thermostat from sub panel question

Tags: subpanel

I am installing quiet warm in floor mats in a small room.We installed a four breaker sub panel.The thermostat for the floors heating pads has a built in gfci,but just shows neutral and hot connections and no ground connection.Do you think this means they are using the neutral wire from the thermostat as ground?Would this work, or would I have to wire the thermostat back to the main service panel? This is a dedicated circuit.I had trouble contacting theyre tech support.Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you, mike s.

Answer (score 2):

GFCI does not require a ground connection to function. It checks for an imbalance between the HOT and NEUTRAL lead current, assuming that any difference is escaping to ground, possibly through a human body.

This is why it is legal to use a GFCI outlet without a ground connected, assuming you are installing it on an old non-grounded circuit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and quick response.   Mike s.

Comment: I can't believe its legal to use a GFCI that's ungrounded there ( I assume you are in the USA).  in Canada, its a cardinal rule (OEC 10-106 and Appendix B, and CSA C22.2) that it must be grounded.  its like you guys choose to live in the dark ages.

Comment: In the US, it is quite legal, so long as the circuit **never** had a ground. This is the legal way to upgrade an existing 2-wire circuit to to a 3-prong outlet. Otherwise, you would need to pull a new ground wire. A GFCI outlet is every bit as safe without a ground as with, although it would provide other ground functions such as working with a surge protector.

Answer (score 0):

NO, they are not using the neutral as a ground. If all you are talking about is the thermostat then it is likely all plastic and does not need a ground. The cable for the floor heat element is typically shielded where the shield is the ground. 
As previously stated, the GFI function of the thermostat will operate fine without a grounding means.

A new circuit and new heat equipment MUST all have a grounding means.